# Android Butterknife implementation error saying compile is obsolete and has been replaced with with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, butterknife

I have implemented following in in build.app file

```
//dependency for view implementation
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'
```

in my project but when i am running the application its giving following error:

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see

```
 //code of gradle
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
 compileSdkVersion 28
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xyc.com"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
     }
   }

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

  implementation'com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//recyclerview dependency
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.+'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

//dependency for view implementation
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'
}
```

Comment: can you post the full code in your gradle file?

Comment: Have you tried clicking sync now after your changes?

Comment: yes i have clicked